# C++ Vector not Updating

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

```
void sortVector(vector<simEvent>& eventVector){

    simEvent temp = eventVector.at(0);
    vector<simEvent> tempVector;
    tempVector.clear();
    int index = 0;

    while(!eventVector.empty()){
        for(int i=0; i<eventVector.size(); i++){
            if(temp.getTimeOfEvent() > eventVector.at(i).getTimeOfEvent()){
                temp = eventVector.at(i);
                index = i;
            }
        }
        eventVector.erase(eventVector.begin()+index);
        tempVector.push_back(temp);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<tempVector.size(); i++){
        cout << "Time: " << tempVector.at(i).getTimeOfEvent() << endl;
    }

}
```

When I print, the tempVector, all of the times are the same. I have looked everywhere for an answer to this and can't seem to find anything. Can someone please give this a look?

Comment: You're not resetting temp in the while loop, so it stays as the smallest value that was in the initial eventVector.

Answer (score 2):

You never reset the value of `temp` in the loop. After the first pass it is equal to the largest element in the array; on every subsequent pass it's still the largest so it doesn't change.